# How to use getState in a grid? [ExtJS 4.1]

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1, getstate

Here it says that I can get width (of columns I guess) but only thing I can get is the columns IDs.

```
grid.getState()
```

Edit:
The response of `Ext.encode(grid.getState())`

```
{"columns":[{"id":"280"},{"id":"279"}],"sort":{"property":"DEPARTMAN_NO","direction":"ASC","root":"data"}}
```

Comment: Please post what exactly are you getting as a return from this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original column width is not changed `getState` does not return width info for this column.